# Select min(date), max(date) and group by day from one column - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I'm going nuts soon please help.

I have one column containing `datetime` values.

I need to find min and max for every day.

The data looks like this

```
2012-11-23 05:49:26.000  
2012-11-23 07:55:43.000  
2012-11-23 13:59:56.000  
2012-11-26 07:51:13.000  
2012-11-26 10:23:31.000  
2012-11-26 10:25:09.000  
2012-11-26 16:22:22.000  
2012-11-27 07:30:03.000  
2012-11-27 08:53:47.000  
2012-11-27 10:40:55.000
```

This is what tried so far

```
select distinct(convert(nvarchar, datum, 112)), min(datum), max(datum) 
from myTable
```

but when I

```
Group by
```

I group on all 3 columns...

I seems not to work to set my first select as ColName and Group on this

This is what I want

```
20121123 | 2012-11-23 05:49:26.000 | 2012-11-23 13:59:56.000  
20121126 | 2012-11-26 07:51:13.000 | 2012-11-26 16:22:22.000  
20121127 | 2012-11-27 07:30:03.000 | 2012-11-27 10:40:55.000
```

Comment: `2012-11-23 05:49:26` **IS** the min value for all of the Nov 23rd dates, just as 10:40:55 is the max value for all of the Nov 27th dates. You're getting exactly what you asked for. the min/max timestamps for every set of "days" in the table.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MarcB that is the *desired* results. Not the results they are actually achieving.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert the column in the `GROUP BY` as well.

```
select
  min(datum), max(datum), CONVERT(varchar(8), datum, 112)
from
  dateTable
group by 
  CONVERT(varchar(8), datum, 112)
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb44d/1)

[Here are the list of convert values for dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  (I've chosen 112 for you in this case above)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008+, you can use the `date` data type instead of converting to a character string:

```
select cast(datum as date), min(datum), max(datum) 
from myTable
group by cast(datum as date);
```